# Passed value to function becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm trying to write a script to disable layers in photoshop. So far the first part (first function) works, and it just grabs all the red layers and puts them in an array. Then I call the second function which takes one by one name from the array and passes it to the disabler (showBounds function). However, I'm looking at the input the showBounds receives ("name") and suddenly it stars saying it's getting "undefined". How can this be? what is happening?

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var theLayers = [];

function fillLayerArray(){
    // get number of layers;
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") );
    var applicationDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
    var theNumber = applicationDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("numberOfLayers"));

    // process the layers;

    //var theOthers = new Array;
    for (var m = 0; m <= theNumber; m++) {


                var ref = new ActionReference();
                ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), m);
                var layerDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
                var isBackground = layerDesc.getBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("background"));
                var layerSet = typeIDToStringID(layerDesc.getEnumerationValue(stringIDToTypeID("layerSection")));
                var theName = layerDesc.getString(stringIDToTypeID('name'));
                var theColor = layerDesc.getEnumerationValue(stringIDToTypeID("color"));
                globColor = theColor;
                    if (typeIDToStringID(theColor) == "red" && layerSet != "layerSectionEnd" ) {
                        theLayers.push(theName);
                    }

    };
    hideLayers(theNumber);
    //showBounds(doc.layerSets);

}


function hideLayers(theNumber){
    for (var i = 0; i <= theLayers.length; i++) {
        //app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible = false;   
        currentLayerName = theLayers[i];

         //alert(currentLayerName)

        alert(currentLayerName);
        showBounds(doc.layerSets, currentLayerName);




    }
}


function showBounds(layerNode, name) {    
    for (var i=0; i<layerNode.length; i++) {

        showBounds(layerNode[i].layerSets);

        for(var layerIndex=0; layerIndex < layerNode[i].artLayers.length; layerIndex++) {
            var layer=layerNode[i].artLayers[layerIndex];
            alert(layer.name + name)

            try{

                if (layer.name == name) {
                    layer.visible = 0;
                }
            }catch(e){
            }
        }
    }
}


fillLayerArray();
```

Comment: If I write out all the layer names from the array just before passing one of the names, it's all there. "alert(layer.name + name)" should be listing off layer names on the left side, while the right stays the passed str, however the last two times it becomes "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
i <= theLayers.length
```

Should be

```
i < theLayers.length
```

In hideLayers.

(Also in m <= theNumber .... remember arrays are indexed starting from zero in JS)

Comment: Basic issues like this generally have a dupetarget. (And this one definitely does.)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the catch! However, it still doesn't solve the Undefined issues

Comment: @i3ick because you're doing something weird in there. Why `layerNode` would have length? Is this only supposed to run on groups? Why do you run `showBounds()` from `showBounds()` again?